# What's the best way to use symbols?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, symbols

Which is better?

1.

```
= link_to "Page", "/page", :class => "button", :data => {:theme => "green", :icon => "small-arrow"}
```

2.

```
= link_to "Page", "/page", class: "button", data: {theme: "green", icon: "small-arrow"}
```

3.

```
= link_to "Page", "/page", class: :button, data: {theme: :green, icon: "small-arrow"}
```

I found out that the symbols are the best way to use because of the memory alocation difference between symbols and strings.

I find version 2. as more readable (for me) and i think also more maintainable, because it's easier/faster to see/edit/add separated words (by space or dash) inside a string rather than edit a symbol and transform it to a string (when needed, like adding a second class "button login" or other theme "dark-red", for example).

Is there any serious reason (e.g. performance) to use the notation from 1. or 3. rather than 2.?

Comment: There's really two questions here: hashrocket vs. 1.9 hash syntax, and symbols vs. strings.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Yes, it could be (I am not very experienced in Ruby). But I try to find any good reason why a code style is better over another. And I also said which is the version I prefer and looks more human readable/maintainable.

Comment: Code style is subjective. Some people prefer the hash rocket, while others like it `json` style. [Ruby 1.8 is legacy software](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2011/10/06/plans-for-1-8-7/), so the fact that it doesn't support the "new" hash syntax is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that it's not only about symbols, it's about old and new hash syntax.

I don't like to mix new hash syntax with symbols. New syntax looks well in most cases, for example:

```
{ width: 42, height: 24 }
```

But it looks horrible with symbols:

```
... class: :button ...
```

It is weird and not human readable, in my opinion. I dislike 3rd option. So, I prefer this option (you didn't mention it):

```
= link_to "Page", "/page", :class => :button, 
   :data => { :theme => :green, :icon => "small-arrow" }
```

This is better because `:class` symbol is written similar to `:button` symbol. Symbols should be written in the same syntax in a single line.

Comment: I agree, :something => "Something Else" is my preferred method when programming. It seems easier to read and it keeps up with how most of Rails symbols are written in the models and controllers.

Comment: @de_an777 Not in Rails 4. David Heinemeier Hansson is a fan of the new syntax and it's already been incorporated into generators. Including in the less favored `foo: :bar` form. Might as well get used to it IMO.

Comment: @coreyward Oh, ok cool.  Didn't know that, I'll be sure to start using it then.  I guess I am just so used to using that syntax, but if they are going to start incorporating it more, less code for them and me to wright.  Can't wait for Rails 4.

Answer (score 2):

1. Works in Ruby 1.8 as well as 1.9.
2. Works only in 1.9. `"button"` and `"green"` aren't stored on the heap, and are mutable, however, they accurately convey that the value of them is what is important.
3. Works only in 1.9. `:button` and `:green` are faster (marginally), at the expense of code that more poorly describes its intent.

In other words, 2 and 3 are the same in terms of the hash syntax. 1 and 2 are the same in terms of correct usage of strings vs symbols.

Comment: I believe the symbols will only be faster if they've already been used. If it's the first (and only) time then there's no advantage.

Comment: Yes, all of them works, but I prefer to use version 2 over 1 or 3 because it describes the intent (as you said) and I find it more maintainable when you change the values of each hash, more readable.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall The symbol :button for e.g. could be used a lot, but it's not that fast when you have to edit (string vs. symbol) when you want to add another words that are separated (by space or dash). And also not that readable.

Comment: @user1454404 Btw, "for e.g." expands to "for for example", there's no need for the "for" in front of "e.g.". It's like saying ATM machine ("Automatic Teller Machine machine") `:)`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall you're right, I've just checked the abbreviation, thank you… but let's keep it on topic

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Symbols and strings shorter than 24 characters are faster than strings longer than 23 characters, simply because they're stored on the heap (not in the actual RString structure). Regardless, the difference is negligible in practice — use whichever makes more sense in the code. Interested in reading more? http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/1/4/never-create-ruby-strings-longer-than-23-characters

Comment: @coreyward Yes I'm aware of that, but I was talking about how symbols are not garbage collected, whereas strings are. This makes symbols faster for subsequent accesses because there is no allocation needed—the object already exists.